# Export a MySQL table via JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, export, inner-join

I was wondering if rather than creating another table to store the results of the MySQL JOIN query is it possible to just export a queries result, like to a CSV?

The query for example would be something like this..

```
SELECT 
    us.id,
    CONCAT_WS(' - ',cats_sic_us.sic,cats_sic_us.category) AS sic_cat
FROM
    us
    INNER JOIN cats_sic_us ON us.sic=cats_sic_us.id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup;

```
SELECT 
    us.id,
    CONCAT_WS(' - ',cats_sic_us.sic,cats_sic_us.category) AS sic_cat
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
    us
    INNER JOIN cats_sic_us ON us.sic=cats_sic_us.id;
```

Comment: +1: Beat me by 35 seconds - here's the [link to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Any reason why adding a FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\' causes an error?

Comment: Provide the full line! If you're already defining "FIELDS TERMINATED BY..." you should remove the "FIELDS" keyword: "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'..."

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe use

```
 select into outfile
```